# XAMPP 5.6.34 for Windows 2012 R2 how to get Apache::ASP working

Tags: apache, perl, xampp, mod-perl, mod-perl2

I am working on a previous version of XAMPP that someone else built, I'm updating it to the following version in a separate directory, but the new installation doesn't seem to have mod_perl which I think is needed for Apache::ASP.

XAMPP 5.6.34 for Windows 
Includes: Apache 2.4.29, MariaDB 10.1.31, PHP 5.6.34, phpMyAdmin 4.7.9, OpenSSL 1.0.2, XAMPP Control Panel 3.2.2, Webalizer 2.23-04, Mercury Mail Transport System 4.63, FileZilla FTP Server 0.9.41, Tomcat 7.0.56 (with mod_proxy_ajp as connector), Strawberry Perl 7.0.56 Portable

Essentially, there is a mod_perl.so in the previous installation that is not in the new installation.  The previous installation has perl510.dll, the new installation has perl516.dll  Essentially, configurations like PerlModule Apache::ASP and PerlResponseHandler Apache::ASP are not working.

So I thought I needed to download the mod_perl add-on (which I can't easily find), then I read "...you need to install 'XAMPP Add-Ons' if your version of XAMPP is earlier than 1.7.2, as of this version mod_perl and 'a selection of important Perl Modules' are included as standard."  This implies it is already in place for my version.  Then I read that mod_perl2 is for apache2.x.x, so which version is included?  I don't see the modules in apache/modules.

Further, if I need to install it, the Apache:ASP documentation is very limited and implies I need to compile apache and perl together which just feels wrong since there is a XAMPP bundle.

I need help with understanding the context of how to get Apache::ASP properly installed/configured for this version of XAMPP, not having much experience with any of this.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XAMPP is supposed to ship mod_perl2.](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/os/win32/install.html#All_in_one_packages) The 5.6.34 and 7.2.3 packages don't have it.

I tried to manually install mod_perl2 into the XAMPP bundle. The software is crippled/incomplete. Their Perl doesn't come with [dmake](https://metacpan.org/release/dmake). Their Apache httpd doesn't come with [apxs](http://archive.apache.org/dist/perl/win32-bin/apxs_win32.tar.gz). I tried for a while to work around the problems and follow-up problems, but I think in the end that's a waste of time.

You should contact the "Apache Friends" vendor for support.

Comment: Thank you for the added context daxim... incidentally, I downloaded XAMPP 7.1.15 as well and it didn't have mod_perl either.  That seems unlikely that is would be missing from so many packages... thoughts on that?

Comment: Apparently they don't ship with mod_perl: https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=76790&sid=05d21257ecf5820a25f183af5411dab9